No attempt to send serial data with old program on Windows
I have a 32-bit program from 1999 that sends/receives data via a serial port with some old hardware but when I run the program it seems like it doesn't even attempt to send data.
I've tried with the device connected and with traffic monitors connected and in both cases nothing seems to be sent, but the program reports it can't find the device.
I've tried setting the real port to various configurations, although all have been random as the requirements aren't documented.
I tried creating a virtual port using 'Virtual Serial Port Driver Pro', which would feed traffic from the program to 'Serial Lab' which was logging all serial traffic sent; but it says 0 sent/received.
The only thing to suggest the program is doing something is when I click send, the port changes to 19200 then a moment later to 9600. It's possible the device is supposed to send a signal when this happens, if it can detect it?, but I don't know how to do that.
When the device is connected, it automatically displays on screen that it's now ready to download data but doesn't appear to send any traffic to the computer. (I believe this is just based on power coming through the cable)
I don't have the source code for the program. I don't think it's the cable as there was no data even with a virtual port.
I did also try running the program in a virtualbox Windows XP VM with a virtual port and monitor and also with port forwarding but nothing happened there either.
The hardware is:

Computer: Windows 11 laptop
Device: Sharp Wizard ZQ/OZ-770
Cable: USB-RS232 -> RS232 Gender changer -> RS232-3.5m jack

The only options I've been able to come up with are:

The program uses an old API that isn't supported on Windows 11, but that doesn't explain why it also didn't work on XP (also the program doesn't show any errors or crash)
It's waiting on a signal, but the neither side sends anything
The monitor/virtual programs don't work properly or interfer with the program


Serial connections don't provide any speed indication (except for "data looks like garbage") so the device won't be looking for that... Does the virtual serial port software show any activity on the various handshake lines (DTR RTS etc.)? If it does, can you try to set the port to "software flow control" or "no flow control"? Entirely out of curiosity, did it work in the past with this specific adapter combination, and is it a straight-through 'gender changer' adapter or a cross-over 'null modem' one?

Actually, given that it's from 1999, have you tried a Windows 98 or WinME VM instead? I don't think the serial API has changed any between XP and modern systems, but it's very possible it would have changed between Win9x and NT.

@grawity_u1686
I can not find a monitor that shows the state of the lines;
I've never used this cable before today;
It's a straight-through;
Tried a 98 VM and it still doesn't send anything;
I wired up a bunch of LEDs to the serial cable and it appears the program does work even on Windows 11 as the CTS and RD lit up, but either the cable isn't working correctly or needs the 3.5mm wiring to be different.

+1 for a problem well-stated.
